# PHP DOMDocument replace multiple child with text nodes

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I've one sample string as follows :

```php
$feed_status = 'Nice to see you all back again
<img src="http://example.com/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" />
<img src="http://example.com/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" />
<img src="http://example.com/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" />';
```

For this example I've just added three `<img>` tags to the string but in real situation this string could contain a zero or more `<img>` tags.

I want to get names of files present in each of the `<img>` tag's src attribute and make array of those file names. Then I have to replace these `<img>` tags by strings from an array titled `$emoticon_codes` which is created dynamically based on the file name present in `<img>` tag. This replacement of strings should happen is the same order.

For this I've tried following code. Till the creation of dynamic array titled `$emoticon_codes` everything works fine but I'm facing with code for replacing the current `<img>` tags with the strings from the array `$emoticon_codes`. So can somebody please help me in correcting the mistake I'm making in my code while replacing the `<img>` tags from the string.

Following is my code :

```php
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($feed_status);
  $imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
  
  if(count($imageTags)) {
    $emoticon_codes = array();
    foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
      if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'evilgrin.png') {
        array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue404');
      }
      if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'grin.png') {
        array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue415');
      }
      if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'happy.png') {
        array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue057');
      }
      if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'smile.png') {
        array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue056');
      }
      if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'surprised.png') {
        array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue107');
      }
      if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'tongue.png') {
        array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue105');
      }
      if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'unhappy.png') {
        array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue403');
      }
      if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'waii.png') {
        array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue407');
      }
      if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'wink.png') {
        array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue405');
      }
    }
    /*Till here everything works fine. The array $emoticon_codes is also getting generated finely*/
 
    /*Following is the code giving problem to me,*/
    $t = 0;
    
    foreach($imageTags as $img) {
      $img->parentNode->replaceChild($img, $doc->createTextNode($emoticon_codes[$t]));
      $t++;
      if ($t > count($emoticon_codes)) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

My desired output string should be like follows after `echo $feed_status;` :

> **Nice to see you all back again \ue056 \ue056 \ue056;**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to change multiple children, you need some [regression](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php#50500) to make some changes, and I suggest try to map each replacement in an array instead of having multiple if statements. Example:

```
$feed_status = "Nice to see you all back again <img src=\"http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" title=\"v_middle\" /><img src=\"http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" title=\"v_middle\" /><img src=\"http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" title=\"v_middle\" />";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($feed_status, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

$replacements = array(
    'evilgrin.png' => '\ue404',
    'grin.png' => '\ue415',
    'happy.png' => '\ue057',
    'smile.png' => '\ue056',
    'surprised.png' => '\ue107',
    'tongue.png' => '\ue105',
    'unhappy.png' => '\ue403',
    'waii.png' => '\ue407',
    'wink.png' => '\ue405',
);

// regression 
$i = $imageTags->length - 1;
while($i > -1) {
    $tag = $imageTags->item($i);
    $basename = basename($tag->getAttribute('src'));
    if(isset($replacements[$basename])) { // if the file name matches
        // make replacements
        $r = $replacements[$basename];
        $text = $doc->createTextNode($r);
        $tag->parentNode->replaceChild($text, $tag);
    }
    $i--;
}
// append to string container again
$feed_status = '';
foreach($doc->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes as $e) {
    $feed_status .= $doc->saveHTML($e);
}
echo $feed_status;
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nHPip5)

Comment: Thank you so much for your immense help. It worked superbly for me. Thanks once again from bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
foreach($imageTags as $img) {
  $img->parentNode->replaceChild($img, $doc->createTextNode($emoticon_codes[$t]));
  $t++;
  if ($t > count($emoticon_codes)) {
    break;
  }
}
```

However that only loops through `$imageTags`, not `$emoticon_codes`.

You need this:

```
foreach($imageTags as $img) {
      foreach($emoticon_codes as $emoticon_code) {
              $img->parentNode->replaceChild($img, $doc->createTextNode($emoticon_code));
      }
}
```

Comment: Still the same issue.  In my code I'm using each element from the array $emoticon_codes by using variable $t and I'm initializing and increasing it too by one with each iteration. There must be some other issue.